# Scrolling issue in RecyclerView in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have added RecyclerView in NestedScrollView like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And in Java code I have specified the height like this

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(new DataManager());   
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setMinimumHeight(3000);
```

Can anyone tell me what height should I pass so that RecyclerView work properly?

Comment: why do you wrap your recycler view in a nestedscrollview?

Comment: Very bad idea to wrap recycler view in a scroll view

Comment: Please suggest what should I do to solve this?

Comment: @DhavalGulhane, if RecyclerView is the only child you have inside NestedScrollView, then replace NestedScrollView with linearlayout

Comment: Is it for toolbar hide/show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try [this](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/adapters/SimpleStaggeredAdapter.java).
>
> Here `setMinimumHeight(height)` is used where height is calculated dynamically.